# python string interpolation

Tags: python, string, string-interpolation

What could generate the following behavior ?

```
>>> print str(msg)
my message
>>> print unicode(msg)
my message
```

But:

```
>>> print '%s' % msg
another message
```

More info:

- my `msg` object is inherited from `unicode`.
- the methods `__str__`/`__unicode__`/`__repr__` methods were overridden to return the string `'my message'`.
- the `msg` object was initialised with the string `'another message'`.
- this is running on python 2.5
- the variable `msg` was not changed between the tests
- this is actually real doctest that is really giving these results.

I would like an solution that matches this doctest, with minimal fuss (especially around the actual inheritance):

```
>>> print '%s' % msg
my message
```

Thanks for all suggestions.

I don't feel this will help more, but for curious readers (and adventurous pythonist), here's the implementation of the object:

```
class Message(zope.i18nmessageid.Message):

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(zope.i18n.interpolate(self.default, self.mapping))

    def __str__(self):
        return zope.i18n.interpolate(self.default, self.mapping)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return zope.i18n.interpolate(self.default, self.mapping)
```

This is how we create the object msg:

```
>>> msg = Message('another message', 'mydomain', default='my message')
```

Zope packages version and code used are:

- zope.i18n-3.4.0 ([interpolation() method code](http://svn.zope.org/zope.i18n/tags/3.4.0/src/zope/i18n/__init__.py?rev=80517&view=markup) )
- zope.i18nmessageid-3.4.3 ([Message class code](http://svn.zope.org/zope.i18nmessageid/tags/3.4.3/src/zope/i18nmessageid/message.py?rev=80112&view=markup))

EDIT INFO:

- added/updated the names of the methods that were overriden
- added some more info (python version, and minor info)
- updated some wrong info (the class of `msg` is based on `unicode` class and not `basestring`)
- added the actual implementation of the class used

Comment: @extraneon: it's python 2.x: `print` is a statement, basestring, unicode!

Comment: changing the value of `msg` variable between `print` s would explain it

Comment: Have you got the actual code for that object? (Or rather its class.) It would be useful if you could paste it in here...

Comment: @vaab, is msg's class implementation top secret? otherwise I would like to see it

Comment: @vaab, my apologies for my wrong answer, that I've since deleted.  This seems like a bug in Python internals to me, so I would open a bug in Python's tracker (with simplified code like Michal's below).

Comment: As a bug workaround while waiting for a fixed Python version, it seems to me that Paul has the right idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update 2:* Please find the original answer, including a simple example of a class exhibiting the behaviour described by the OP, below the horizontal bar. As for what I was able to surmise in the course of my inquiry into Python's sources (v. 2.6.4):

The file `Include/unicodeobject.h` contains the following to lines (nos. 436-7 in my (somewhat old) checkout):

```
#define PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(op) \                                              
        (((PyUnicodeObject *)(op))->str)
```

This is used all over the place in the formatting code, which, as far as I can tell, means that during string formatting, any object which inherits from `unicode` will be reached into so that its unicode string buffer may be used directly, without calling any Python methods. Which is good as far as performance is concerned, I'm sure (and very much in line with Juergen's conjecture in a comment on this answer).

For the OP's question, this probably means that making things work the way the OP would like them to may only be possible if something like Anurag Uniyal's wrapper class idea is acceptable for this particular use case. If it isn't, the only thing which comes to my mind now is to wrap objects of this class in `str` / `unicode` wherever their being interpolated into a string... ugh. (I sincerely hope I'm just missing a cleaner solution which someone will point out in a minute!)

---

(*Update:* This was posted about a minute before the OP included the code of his class, but I'm leaving it here anyway (1) for the conjecture / initial attempt at an explanation below the code, (2) for a simple example of how to produce this behaviour (Anurag Uniyal has since provided another one calling `unicode`'s constructor directly, as opposed to via `super`), (3) in hope of later being able to edit in something to help the OP in obtaining the desired behaviour.)

Here's an example of a class which actually works like what the OP describes (Python 2.6.4, it does produce a deprecation warning -- `/usr/bin/ipython:3: DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters`):

```
class Foo(unicode):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(unicode, self).__init__(msg)
    def __str__(self): return 'str msg'
    def __repr__(self): return 'repr msg'
    def __unicode__(self): return u'unicode msg'
```

A couple of interactions in IPython:

```
In [12]: print(Foo("asdf"))
asdf

In [13]: str(Foo("asdf"))
Out[13]: 'str msg'

In [14]: print str(Foo("asdf"))
-------> print(str(Foo("asdf")))
str msg

In [15]: print(str(Foo("asdf")))
str msg

In [16]: print('%s' % Foo("asdf"))
asdf
```

Apparently string interpolation treats this object as an instance of `unicode` (directly calling the `unicode` implementation of `__str__`), whereas the other functions treat it as an instance of `Foo`. How this happens internally and why it works like this and whether it's a bug or a feature, I really don't know.

<strike>As for how to fix the OP's object... Well, how would I know without seeing its code??? Give me the code and I promise to think about it!</strike> Ok, I'm thinking about it... No ideas so far.

Comment: Looks to me, as print has made some shortcut -- to speed up things, I would think. Python has (relatively fast) internal interfaces and (relatively slow) external interfaces. I guess, that somebody tried to avoid the overhead ...

Comment: @Juergen: Included some info on what the sources look like in the answer now... It certainly seems that you're right.

Comment: @Michal: Thanks for the info! Python is rather clean as a system, but (as much I understand it and also have seen a little bit of) sometimes some shortcuts are made internally where a big speed advantage can be gained. This is OK in my opinion, since those shortcuts are not visible in 99% of all cases ... in the other 1%, a workaround must be made like in this case. Of course, when stumpling over one, it can be rather surprising or even annoying ...

Comment: @Juergen: Agreed. Perhaps for cases like this some flag (visible from C) could be set on the object to indicate that it overrides a builtin's methods and thus needs to be treated in the slow way... I'm hardly competent to judge though. I guess if vaab goes on to make the bug report, then we'll find out what the Python team's opinion is.

Answer (score 6):

So problem is class like to something below behaves weirdly

```
class Msg(unicode):
    def __init__(self, s):
        unicode.__init__(self, s)

    __unicode__ = __repr__ = __str__ = lambda self: "my message"

msg = Msg("another message")
print str(msg)
print unicode(msg)
print "%s"%msg
```

this prints

```
my message
my message
another message
```

I am not sure why this happens or how to fix it, but a very crude attempt by wrapping Msg, but not sure it will help in OP's problem

```
class MsgX(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._msg = Msg(s)

    __unicode__ = __repr__ = __str__ = lambda self: repr(self._msg)

msg = MsgX("another message")
print str(msg)
print unicode(msg)
print "%s"%msg
```

output:

```
my message
my message
my message
```

Comment: I cannot afford to change the inheritage towards unicode. However, thanks for you simplified example.

Comment: @vaab: if you look at the extended answer I gave, the addition of `__getattr__` will forward all accessors that *would* have been resolved by inheritance to the contained .msg attribute. This is a very powerful idiom in Python, and puts wrap-and-delegate on par with inheritance, with less coupling.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you are trying to extend a built-in.  Magic `__` methods don't get called for builtins.  I think you will have to do some kind of wrap-and-delegate, like this (untested) (maybe Anurag beat me to the punch):

```
class Message(object): 

    def __init__(self, strvalue, domain, default='my message'):
        self.msg = zope.i18nmessageid.Message(strvalue,domain,default)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.msg,attr)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return repr(zope.i18n.interpolate(self.msg.default, self.msg.mapping)) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return zope.i18n.interpolate(self.msg.default, self.msg.mapping) 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return zope.i18n.interpolate(self.msg.default, self.msg.mapping)
```

***Update 1*** - it seems that `__` methods *do* get called for subclasses of builtins

```
>>> class Z(int):
...   def __add__(self,other): return self*other
...   def __str__(self): return "***"
...
>>> a = Z(100)
>>> a + 2
200
>>> a
100
>>> str(a)
'***'
>>> "%s" % a
'***'
```

So there is definitely some inconsistency going on...

Comment: Great Idea, but this does not work ! ;) Well it works for the given doctest, but the fact this class is not anymore an instance of `string` break some other C checks in Python common libraries that I use and need to use. I'll be more clear tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, you (or those libs) are using isinstance, perhaps?  And now this class no longer inherits from basestring?  Hmmm, those isinstance checks wouldn't happen to be doing parameter validation would they?  This is an excellent case showing why isinstance parameter checking is not always the best idea in Python.